# Cross platform mixpanel tracking inside a webview

Tags: flutter, webview, mixpanel

My app uses a webview to display my website. I've added mixpanel tracking in both the website and the app. But since they are different platforms, the tracking is not synced. Events performed in the app are tracked with a different distinct_id than the one from the website. Is there a way to sync the events (helpful to build funnels) by setting the website's distinct_id as the app's distinct_id?

When I try to do it I get an error that says : Can't identify with '$device:' distinct_id.